# ReactJS export multiple wrapper functions one component

Tags: reactjs

In react I'm trying to export a class called IconButtons, the current export I have is this:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(IconButtons);
```

This works great, but decided my app needed Redux, so I need to add the Connect wrapper function.  I tried the following code:

```
const iconExports = { 
    reduxConnect() { connect(mapStateToProps)(IconButtons) },
    stylesExport() { withStyles(styles)(IconButtons)}
}

export default iconExports;
```

This gives me an error:

```
type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a 
class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

How do I use both of these functions for one export?

Comment: Try `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(IconButtons));`

Comment: I'm assuming the error shows when you try to use the imported iconExports.   The imported iconExports is now an object, and where you're using it is expecting a String.  Show us that code, but you probably just need to pass in iconExports.stylesExport() instead.

Comment: Try `reduxConnect() { return connect(...` and `stylesExport() { return with...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: `export default withStyles(styles)(connect(mapStateToProps)(IconButtons))`

Why? In your first example, you're exporting *a single component*, which is the result of calling `withStyles(styles)(IconButtons)`. When you changed it, you created an object with two methods: `reduxConnect` and `stylesExport`. Each of them returns a different component. I don't know how you were trying to use this exported value, but I assume this is not what you intended, and that what you want is a single component that uses wrapped in both `connect` and `withStyles`.

I suggest you read about higher order components (both `connect` and `withStyles` are functions that return higher order components). The short story is that a HoC wraps a component and returns a new one. So, `connect` expects you to give it a component and returns a connected component. You can then give that component to `withStyles`. A more verbose solution that will perhaps make everything more clear is this:

```js
const connectedIconButtons = connect(mapStateToProps)(IconButtons)
const connectedIconButtonsWithStyles = withStyles(styles)(connectedIconButtons)

export default connectedIconButtonsWithStyles
```

See how you first wrap `IconButtons` with `connect`, and then rewrap it with `withStyles`.